# Convert string dates to datetimes in javascript, what to do with dateformat

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to convert a string which is a date to a real date that I can use to compare which dates is the earliest.

The dates I have is in this format "January 2, 2010"
I know I should use some sort of dateformat of a kind, but not sure how to do in when using javascript.

This is the code I got:

```
function checkOutboundAndReturnDates(outboundDate, returnDate) {
    var outboundDatetime = new Date(outboundDate);
    var returnDatetime = new Date(returnDate);
    var date = new Date("2017-03-25");
    console.log(outboundDate);
    console.log(returnDate);
    console.log("Converting dates");
    console.log(outboundDatetime);
    console.log(returnDatetime);
    console.log(date);

    // String string = "January 2, 2010";
    // DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    // Date date = format.parse(string);
}
```

The var date is working, but that is just for testing, not what I want.
got the day in number, the year in the number but the month in text, like I wrote:

```
"January 2, 2010"
```

**Update**

```
 var outboundDateTime = moment(outboundDate, "MMMM DD, YYYY");
var returnDateTime = moment(returnDate, "MMMM DD, YYYY");

console.log(outboundDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log(returnDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

if (outboundDateTime > returnDateTime) {
    console.log("its bigger");
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

on top of my js file I have:

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

Have installed it via npm.

Comment: What's the problem? `var date = new Date("January 2, 2010");`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev—because parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is implementation dependent and **strongly** recommended against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for working with dates in js. You can parse your date string with moment like this:

```
var outboundDateTime = moment(outboundDate, "MMMM DD, YYYY");
```

and format it with

```
console.log(outboundDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

or check which one is earlier with

```
console.log(outboundDateTime.isBefore(inboundDateTime));
```

```js
var dateString1 = "January 2, 1999";
var dateString2 = "January 21, 1999";
var format = "MMMM DD, YYYY";

var outboundDateTime = moment(dateString1, format);
var returnDateTime = moment(dateString2, format);

console.log(outboundDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log(returnDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

if (outboundDateTime.isAfter(returnDateTime)) {
    console.log("its bigger");
    
}
else {
    console.log("not");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I have done it right.. getting invalid date when using moment.. see my update in a min.

Comment: @Mandersen I'm not sure where the error comes from - see the code snippet, it's working. Are you sure all your input strings have the same format?

Comment: Working now.. was my mistake.. thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have different input string formats, just pass an array  with format strings... @Mandersen

Comment: Why define the *format* variable and then not use it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to used third party js like then this code may be help you.

```
var months = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = months[date.getMonth()];
var year = date.getFullYear();

console.log(date);
console.log(month+" "+day+", "+year);
```